# React-Native Jest PropType Test

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-proptypes

Im trying to write a jest test that tests the  actual type of a propType, not the type of the value passed in.  Can anyone help please?

this is what i have so far, but this just test the input type, not the actual type in the component code...

```
describe('PropTypes should be correct type', () => {
  it('should have correct proptype types', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SimpleList />).instance()
    expect(typeof wrapper.props.data).not.toBe(Array)
    expect(typeof wrapper.props.style).not.toBe(Object)
  })
})
```

Thanks